# Calling a function somewhere else inside a script tag doesn't work

Tags: javascript

For some reason, the code in the same script tag work well, but calling the function that contains the same code from other script tag doesn't.

In my code I have a google map script in the header and it works very well let's call this script tag (A).

The problem is that when I'm not in the script tag A and want to call a function that is in the script A from another script tag to reuse it. it will not work. however if I copied the code from that function and put it directly in the same tag it will work.

I want to be able to call it not to write it again. what is the wrong thing in my code??

The complete code:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>
<script>
//this is the function that I want call
function getAddress(location) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat(), location.lng());
    geocoder.geocode({
        latLng: latLng
    },
        function (responses) {
            if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
                $("#addressResult").text(responses[0].formatted_address);
                // alert(responses[0].formatted_address);
            } else {
                alert('Cannot determine address at this location.');
            }
        });
}
var map;
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850);

function initialize() {
    var mapProp = {
        center: myCenter,
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);

    });

}
var marker
function placeMarker(location) {
    if (marker) {
        marker.setPosition(location);
    } else {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map
        });
    }
    //calling it inside and it's working
    getAddress(location);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>


<body>
<label>Location: </label>
                    <label id="addressResult"></label>
                    <input type="button" value="Current Location" onclick="getLocation()" />
<script>
                            var x = document.getElementById("addressResult");
                        function getLocation() {
                            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
                            } else {
                                x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
                            }
                        }

                        function showPosition(position) {
                           //here where I want to call it
                            getAddress(position);
                            }
</script>
  <div id="googleMap" style="width: 500px; height: 380px;"></div>

                        <div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure your second script block is after the element with id `addressResult`. Even better, put everything in the head and use proper onload handling.

Comment: In the future please provide a complete testcase (right now it's not clear where these `<script>` blocks are located in the HTML) and the specific error you get.

Comment: @EdCottrell yes it's after the element with id    `addressResult`

Comment: @Nickolay sorry I thought it was clear when I mentioned the place of the first script tag in my explanation which is in the head tag. I added them now.

Comment: @Nysa, you still don't have a complete example and provide no indication of what the error is. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve // Right now you don't have a `<script>` tag at all in the second snippet. Also it seems that your code expects the value from `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` to have `.lat()` and `.lng()` methods, while it's actually a [Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Position) object. Check out [this doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation#DetectingUserLocation) to see an example converting it to `google.maps.LatLng()`

Comment: @Nickolay unfortunately no errors. simply not working or showing any thing. I will add what is missing so you can check it.

Comment: @Nysa: "does not print the address in #addressResult, no errors in the console" is exactly the kind of description that helps us help you. You **should** get an error though (I do!). Try adding `console.log(position)` to showPosition - do you see it logged? (Do you know how to use the browser's console?) If you don't, you might have disabled geolocation in the browser or it doesn't work for another reason.

Comment: @Nickolay no I haven't used the browser's console before.  I also checked the geolocation in the browser it wasn't disabled. I get the result if I put the code inside the function `getAddress()` in the second script that's why I'm confused.

Comment: You should definitely learn to use the console. Did you see the error before fixing up `showPosition` to do the conversion? What was the error? (I don't believe that simply moving the `getAddress` function to another `<script>` makes any difference -- something else must be going on.)

Comment: @Nickolay I just learned how to use the console and the error I got: location.lat is not a function. Now finally it works thank you so much you really helped me a lot ( with the console) .what you have posted is correct I just needed to change the place and now it's working .

Comment: Excellent, glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ed mentioned, the problem is probably due to the fact that you put the function call directly in the <script> -- such code executes before the page has finished loading, and may break if something your code depends on is not yet available.

To fix that, put the code in a function that executes after the page is loaded. If you only care about relatively modern browsers, use the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event listener, and if you're using a JS framework it likely provides a way to do it while supporting older browsers.

(Obligatory jQuery plug: if you're using it, the syntax is `$(function() { /* your code here */ });`)

**Update**

It seems you don't convert the results from `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` to a `google.maps.LatLng` value properly. Here's an [example from the Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation#DetectingUserLocation):

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  var initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
```

**Update #2 (from the OP):**
Changing `showPosition` as follows fixed the problem:

```
function showPosition(position) {
   var initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
                           position.coords.latitude, 
                           position.coords.longitude);

   getAddress(initialLocation);
}
```

Comment: I tried putting the code in jquery ready here `$(function() { /* your code here */ });` still not working.